# How to determine which variables best differentiate a categorial variable

Tags: importance

I have a collection of flagship phones, each characterised by several continuous numerical variables: screen size, megapixels, RAM, storage, RRP, etc. I am trying to work out which variables best characterise each flagship phone. Ideally, I would generate some metric that quantifies the importance of each variable in differentiating the specific phone.

Is there a statistical analysis that can help me to tell which features best differentiate the different phones.

One option would be for any given variable to calculate the sum of the squared and normalised differences eg. the sum of the squared and normalised differences between the iPhone's price and each of the competitor's price.

Would this be a sensible analysis? Or is there any conventional method to answer my question?

Comment: i would interpret this problem as: Can i predict the brand of a phone by using the given set of variables and if so, which of this variables has the biggest impact on the prediction. Therefor i would try a multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: Some brands are similar.  I see this more of a problem of characterizing combinations of features that are most different over all phones.  This is done in marketing to characterize customers using features other than what they purchase.  I wish I knew the name of this unsupervised learning technique.  It is related to clustering of observations.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the multinomial logistic regression. However, I'm not sure that these techniques are compatible with my data since I have (a) no repeats - ie. each brand is characterised by only a single flagship phone and (b) I have many (30) variables so my results will be unstable. Do you think your technique can handle these data?